# Any way to store time intervals with more than 24h

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Currently I have table that stores the time duration in following format *hh:mm:ss* using *CHAR(10)* columns. It seems that *TIME(0)* is good alternative to store such values to be able to do aggregations on them later. However it has limitation with the max value of *23:59:59*. In my case I have data with more than 24h. Is there any way to store such values? One of the possible way is to store it in *DATETIME* column with the start date of *1900.01.01* (or some other date) and then add the data there, but it adds complexity on how the data is supposed to be extracted from this value and also additional changes must be done to the source of this data. Is there any other nice way of doing that?

Comment: Duration is a number and not a string, why don't you use int/bigint/decimal to store the duration in seconds?

Comment: Or record a start and end time using `datetime` or `datetime2` columns?

Comment: @sepupic It might be solution, but it adds also complexity of changing the way how the data is used + populated.

Comment: @iamdave it is even more complicated than integers. I'll need to add 1 more extra column for each column like that.  I have ~10 of them in the table.

Comment: You are recording *10* time intervals in the one table...?  Perhaps you need to redesign your schema.  What are you recording these intervals for, exactly?

Comment: Also, adding 10 columns into one table is far from a complex change...

Comment: @iamdave if there would be just a table then it is OK, however there are consumers/source of this table also

Comment: Then any change you do is going to be complex, because everything that interacts with those columns will be expecting a string value and you're changing it to a `time` or a number or a `datetime` value.  That work will always be present no matter what change you do.

Answer (score 2):

`time` is not appropriate - as you've discovered, it has a number of "limitations" such as the inability to add values together or store >24 hours or negative values. (They're not really limitations - they exist because this type is clearly designed to model a *time of day*, **not** a *duration*. Although we frequently confuse these concepts, they *ought* to have separate data types and in this case, SQL Server only has one and it's the first of those types).

I prefer to avoid any string representations (leaving any such conversions to a presentation layer) and don't like to abuse inappropriate data types (such as your `datetime` suggestion). I instead model such items with names such as "durationMS" or "durationS" or even "durationSeconds" and then use an integral or decimal data type as the type of the column. This makes aggregation easy and you can obviously store large or negative values. You pick the units to match the lowest level of granularity you will need.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of years ago, I wrote a CLR data type around the .NET TimeSpan class. Here's a [github link](https://github.com/ben-thul/SQLCLR/blob/master/SQLCLR/User%20Defined%20Types/Duration.cs). If you use this, you'd define your column to have the Duration datatype.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.IO;


[Serializable]
[SqlUserDefinedType(
    Format.UserDefined,
    MaxByteSize = sizeof(long) + sizeof(bool),
    IsFixedLength = true,
    IsByteOrdered = true
)]
public class Duration: INullable, IBinarySerialize, IComparable
{
    private TimeSpan _ts;
    private bool _null;

    public Duration(TimeSpan ts)
    {
        _ts = ts;
        _null = false;
    }

    public Duration()
    {
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _ts.ToString();
    }

    public bool IsNull
    {
        get
        {
            return _null;
        }
    }

    public static Duration Null
    {
        get
        {
            Duration h = new Duration();
            h._null = true;
            return h;
        }
    }

    public static Duration Parse(SqlString s)
    {
        if (s.IsNull)
            return Null;
        Duration u = new Duration();
        u._ts = TimeSpan.Parse(s.Value);
        return u;
    }

    public TimeSpan timeSpan
    {
        get
        {
            return _ts;
        }
    }

    public void Write(BinaryWriter w)
    {
        w.Write(_null);
        w.Write(_ts.Ticks);
    }

    public void Read(BinaryReader r)
    {
        _null = r.ReadBoolean();
        _ts = new TimeSpan(r.ReadInt64());
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        Duration otherDuration = (Duration)obj;
        return _ts.CompareTo(otherDuration._ts);
    }
}
```